# <A> attribute gives Edit cursor on hover

Tags: html, css

I am defining three menu buttons

```
<div id="buttonscontainer">
    <ul>
    <li><a unselectable="on" value="insert" onClick="insertText('[BEFORE]', '[AFTER]'); return false;">Bold</a></li>
    <li><a unselectable="on" value="insert" onClick="insertText('[BEFORE]', '[AFTER]'); return false;">Italic</a></li>
    <li><a unselectable="on" value="insert" onClick="insertText('[BEFORE]', '[AFTER]'); return false;">Image</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I use `<a>` tag to create simple text button with OnClick jscript.

The problem is that when user hovers over the link the cursors is changed to edit (like editbox cursor)

Why is that behaviuor? Or do I have to look in CSS for particular attribute

Comment: Can you link to a working jsFiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to add the `href` attribute to your anchor or in CSS you can add:

```
#buttonscontainer a:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Either of those will change the cursor to the pointer :)

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/AUyj6/).

Answer (score 3):

I *think* the problem is that you need to add a `href` attribute to your links:

```
<a .. href="#">Bold</a>
```

Or, you could add this CSS:

```
a {
    cursor: pointer
}
```

but that seems a little silly. Just add the `href`, and [*fix the styling of the links (demo)*](http://jsfiddle.net/UJHDN/).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that your  tag is missing required atribute href.
Try putting in empty href=""